# Test method to support getContent call

Tags: unit-test

I have created getContent() method to send a pdf page in email using Visualforce page. But while running test method on the controller, I am getting following error message -
"Methods defined as TestMethod do not support getContent call, test skipped"
How to fix this problem.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There's a few ways to do this.  My personal preference is to generate a different Blob for the body of the page depending on whether my code is running in the test context:

So if I have a reference to the page in variable pr:

```
   Blob content;
   if (Test.IsRunningTest())
   {
        content=Blob.valueOf('UNIT.TEST');
   }
   else
   {
        content=pr.getContent();
   }
```

and then do whatever I need to do with the body content.

Comment: I'd suggest making it a one-line for test coverage purposes. Something like:
`Blob content = Test.isRunningTest() ? Blob.valueOf('UNIT.TEST') : pr.getContent();`
That way, it'll cover if you could get the content or not.