# Unit test for a Queueable class behaves differently

Tags: unit-test, queueable-apex

I have written a class which implements queueable interface and creates PDFs and saves them as attachments. Which is working fine.

```
public class ExpensePDF_Async_Helper implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts{

            private Set<Id> idset = new Set<Id>();

            public ExpensePDF_Async_Helper(set<id> approvedIdset){

                idset = approvedIdset;            
            }

            public void execute(QueueableContext qc)
            {

                Integer allowedCallouts = Limits.getLimitCallouts() - Limits.getCallouts();

               if(allowedCallouts <=0)
               return;

               list<expense_report__c> pdfsTocreate = new list<expense_report__c>();

               for(Expense_report__c repo :[select PDF_created__c from expense_report__c where id in:Idset LIMIT :allowedCallouts])
               {
                   if(repo.PDF_created__c == false)
                   {
                   // callout for getContentasPDF
                   ExpenseReportPDF.savePDFattachment(repo.id);
                   repo.PDF_Created__c = true;  
                   pdfsTocreate.add(repo);           
                   }
               }
                update PDFsTocreate;// this line doesn't execute in Unit test
            }
    }
```

***Test Class 1: I see that one statements of my original class doesn't get executes in debug log***

```
//Initialization here

    Test.startTest();
    System.enqueueJob(new ExpensePDF_Async_Helper(setId));
    Test.stopTest();

     list<attachment> attach = [select id from attachment where parentid in :setId];

    System.assertEquals(2, attach.size());

    System.assertEquals(true, expReport2.PDF_created__c);
```

I see that below one statements of my original class doesn't get execute if I use Test Class 1 & Test Class 2

```
update PDFsTocreate;
```

***Test Class 2: One statement of my original class doesn't get executes***

```
    Test.startTest();
    ExpensePDF_Async_Helper q = new ExpensePDF_Async_Helper(setId);
    q.execute(null);
    Test.stopTest();

     list<attachment> attach = [select id from attachment where parentid in :setId];

    System.assertEquals(2, attach.size());

    System.assertEquals(true, expReport2.PDF_created__c);
```

The following statement doesn't get executed of my original class

```
update PDFsTocreate;
```

Can someone please explain why update statement in original class is not being called in both the test classes?

Comment: Just fyi, the results of `Limits.getLimitCallouts() - Limits.getCallouts()` are strictly non-negative. It doesn't make sense to check if they're less than 0.

Comment: Well, in your case you want `==`, but yes, that's the idea.

Comment: Can you think of the reason why a DML statement in Queueable class won't execute when called from a test class as in my case?

Comment: FYI also, it seems you have dml in a for loop here

Comment: @zokito No, there's no DML inside loop, the indentation is clear.

Comment: @Bennie `ExpenseReportPDF.savePDFattachment(repo.id);` does this use DML inside?

Comment: Yes, it generates a PDF using getContentasPDF and then saves it as an attachment for the sObject

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason for the error in coverage is because the line

```
ExpenseReportPDF.savePDFattachment(repo.id);
```

is probably executing `getContentAsPDF()` that, [per the Apex Doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_System_PageReference_getContentAsPDF.htm?search_text=pdf) ...

> If you use getContentAsPDF in a test method, the test method fails.
>   getContentAsPDF is treated as a callout in API version 34.0 and later.

There is an [Idea for fixing this](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000HzknAAC)

The inestimable @BobBuzzard has a simple workaround (i.e. `if (Test.isRunningTest() ...)` for this in [his SFSE answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11827/test-method-to-support-getcontent-call). Mohith has a [similar workaround here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/97226/2602)

Comment: Yes, hidden exception seems a likely cause.

Comment: Eric, the class `ExpenseReportPDF` which makes callout. I have taken care of that `Blob content = Test.isRunningTest() ? Blob.valueOf('UNIT.TEST') : pr.getContent();`

Comment: @Bennie -- so the workaround solved your issue or the issue remains?

Comment: Eric, the workaround you suggested was used for different class. This one is a different problem I believe.

Comment: @Bennie.  So if you look at the debug logs you don't see any messages indicating that the test was stopped?